# Temperature logical expressions

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, vdm++

I'm working on some logical expressions. I want to merge 2 expressions into one but not right sure how.
I am using the [VDM Overture Tool](http://www.overturetool.org/).

I am looking at set of 5 temperatures. Some are over 400, some under, etc.

My first expression is true when at least 1 temperature is over 400:

```
OverLimit: TempRead -> bool
OverLimit(temp) == temp(1) > 400 or temp(2) > 400 or 
temp(3) > 400 or temp(4) > 400 or 
temp(5) > 400;`
```

The second expression is true when all values in set are over 400:

```
ContOverLimit: TempRead -> bool 
ContOverLimit(temp) ==
temp(1) > 400 and temp(2) > 400 and 
temp(3) > 400 and temp(4) > 400 and 
temp(5) > 400;
```

The expression I am trying to make now is when at least one temperature is over 400, but not all of them.

Any ideas how to combine these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an existential quantifier. I'm guessing that TempRead is a sequence, so something like:

`exists i in set inds temp & temp(i) > 400`

If you literally mean "but not all of them" you would want an additional "and exists" to check that one existed that was < 400.

Incidentally, be careful combining two `exists` expressions with an `and`: you need to bracket the whole exists expression, otherwise the "and" clause is considered to be part of the first exists!

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind quickly explaining for me what he part "inds temp & temp(i) > 400 mean ? as in how would you read it out in english

Comment: You need to look at the Language Reference Manual (it's on the Overture site). But briefly, the "inds" of a sequence is the set of indexes, so "inds [x,y,z]" is the set {1,2,3}. So in the exists clause, it means "There exists an index in the list such that the temp of that index is over 400" - which sounds like what you want.

Comment: Incidentally, your ContOverLimit should really be a "forall", as in "forall i in set inds temp & temp(i) > 400". Then it would work regardless of the length of the sequence. So "exists" is like a super-or, and "forall" is like a super-and.